# In python how do i sort a txt file in ascending order

Tags: python, sorting

so i have written this code so far to sort a log.txt file into a leaderboard.txt in descending order. But i now want it in ascending order. How do I do that. Heres the file:

```
def extract_log_info(log_file = "log.txt"):
    with open(log_file, 'r') as log_info:
        new_name, new_score = [i.strip('\n') for i in 
        log_info.readlines()[:2]]

    new_score = int(new_score)
    return new_name, new_score

def update_leaderboards(new_name, new_score, lb_file = 
"Leaderboards.txt"):
    cur_index = None
    with open(lb_file, 'r') as lb_info:
        lb_lines = lb_info.readlines()
        lb_lines_cp = list(lb_lines) # Make a copy for iterating over
        for line in lb_lines_cp:
            if 'Leaderboards' in line or line == '\n':
                continue

            # Now we're at the numbers
            position, name, score = [ i for i in line.split() ]

            if new_score > int(score):
                cur_index = lb_lines.index(line)
                cur_place = int(position.strip(')'))
                break

        # If you have reached the bottom of the leaderboard, and there
        # are no scores lower than yours
        if cur_index is None:
            # last_place essentially gets the number of entries thus far
            last_place = int(lb_lines[-1].split()[0].strip(')'))
            entry = "{}) {}\t{}\n".format((last_place+1), new_name, 
            new_score)
            lb_lines.append(entry)
        else: # You've found a score you've beaten
            entry = "{}) {}\t{}\n".format(cur_place, new_name, new_score)
            lb_lines.insert(cur_index, entry)

            lb_lines_cp = list(lb_lines) # Make a copy for iterating over
            for line in lb_lines_cp[cur_index+1:]:
                position, entry_info = line.split(')', 1)
                new_entry_info = str(int(position)+1) + ')' + entry_info
                lb_lines[lb_lines.index(line)] = new_entry_info

    with open(lb_file, 'w') as lb_file_o:
        lb_file_o.writelines(lb_lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name, score = extract_log_info()
    update_leaderboards(name, score)
```

the reason i want it in ascending order is because the game im getting the scores

Comment: Do you know of the `sorted()` function?

Comment: Write into your file in the reverse order of what you are current doing. What's the issue?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use a secondary copy of your files lines? Why not loop through the object using `enumerate()`?

Comment: Could you post some of the data in log.txt?

Comment: [Sorting tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to read a txt file with numbers into a list and then sort using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812578/trying-to-read-a-txt-file-with-numbers-into-a-list-and-then-sort-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already written the file in descending order, just do this:

```
with open('ascending_file.txt', 'r') as ascend:
    lines = ascend.readlines()

with open('descending_file.txt' 'w') as descend:
    ascend.reverse():
    descend.writelines(ascend)
```