# How to swap multiple values on multiple line on notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, swap

I want to swap this value on notepad++, how can i make it simple and work ? please help me for my job with a lot of data like this.

From this

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
```

To This

```
1
11
2
22
3
33
```

I just wanna swap the position, like the example , please help me :)
sorry for bad english

Comment: well, can you make a simple java program in order to make it run ? i can help you with a java program

Comment: You need to decide on an environment you want to work in, and then try produce a minimal working example, showing your code so that we can better answer your question.

Comment: What is your swapping logic?  It looks random to me.

Comment: Here is someone working through a similar problem in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812578/trying-to-read-a-txt-file-with-numbers-into-a-list-and-then-sort-using-python

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sort by ascending order starting with the first character maybe

Answer (score 2):

You just need to sort lines alphabeticaly:

Menu Edit → Line Operations → Sort Lines in Ascending Order

result:

```
1
11
2
22
3
33
```

Comment: ahahah I didn't even think of notepad++'s inbuilt functions, very simple and effective!